# React FirebaseUI - StyledFirebaseAuth

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebaseui

There is a bug in a styling when verifying the number. On fire-fox browser, it looks good and nice but when I tried it on Chrome it looks like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ze4P.png. Does anyone know how to configure this?

Im using this package: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react#readme

```
const uiConfig = {
    signInFlow: 'popup',
    signInOptions: [{ 
      provider: firebaseConfig.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID, 
      defaultCountry: "PH", 
      whitelistedCountries: ['PH', '+63']
    }],
    tosUrl: `${domain}`,
    callbacks: {
      signInSuccessWithAuthResult: () => {
        return false
      }
    },
}


const setUpCaptcha = () => {
        window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebaseConfig.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
            'size': '50px',
            'callback': (response) => {
              onSignInSubmit();
            }
        });
    } 

<StyledFirebaseAuth 
  uiConfig={uiConfig} 
  firebaseAuth={firebaseConfig.auth()}
  uiCallback={ui => ui.disableAutoSignIn()}
/>
```

Comment: Could you pls share some code with us?

Comment: I edited the post already. Thank you!